# Facebook invite on simulator is ok, but can not show appInviteDialog on iOS device

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-invite, facebook-invite-friends

At the same time, `loginDialog` and `shareDialog` can show.

Show `appInviteDialog` error is:

> Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=9 "(null)"

Is there any possibility for a network problem, because I use VPN, but the simulator also uses VPN.

The code:

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content = [[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/319673994858989"];
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by using local iPhone VPN,and appInviteDialog can show.
Before I use computer share network,it may cause network problems for the iOS change the net work safety requirement.Login problems occurred for this network reason before.